# Knapsack with sum of weights of about 10^9

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I encountered a problem in a programming competition a few weeks back, the problem was reducible to knapsack 0/1 problem.

But i couldn't do it because the maximum weight was about 10^9, so in c++ i couldn't use array. Although the number of items were about 10^5.

One way to solve this, that i could think of is using STL map, but not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: @irrelephant ohh, actually it was 10^9, just edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean by too large for an array?

Comment: @user814628 i mean i can't declare an array a[2][10^9] in c.

Comment: sure you can, on heap that should be fine or use std::vector. Or better yet since log(10^9)/log(2) < 30, you try to figure out if you can encode the weights in a 32-bit integer

Comment: @user814628 i can encode weights in 32 bits, but an array of the size i gave above above gives compilation error. http://ideone.com/lznnCN   Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: use this `std::vector<std::vector<int> > c(2,std::vector<int>(1000000000))`. Use it like regular 2d array, like so `c[0][10201] = 0;` and so on

Comment: @user814628 its giving run time error http://ideone.com/lW4XK2

Comment: Try something like so then http://codepad.org/gNckhrsf.

Comment: Are you sure your problem can't be simplified more? Can you please post the original problem in an update to your question?

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs The contest was hosted on UVa, on somewhere about 18th Nov, but unfortunately i didn't copied the problem nor i remember the name of the contest. And the contest is also hidden from UVa past contests. :(

Comment: Ok, now I have a better understanding of your problem, see my next answer, Im sorry about my first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a huge array, why don't you break it down to smaller ones?

```
class Huge_array{
    public:
    Huge_array(size_t max_size):
        max_size(max_size),
        store(max_size/v_size, vector<int>(v_size))
        {}

    int& operator[](size_t index)
    {  
        assert(0<=index && index<max_size); 
        return store[index/v_size][index%v_size]; 
    }

    private:
    size_t max_size;
    const int v_size=100000;
    vector<vector<int> > store;
};
```

I hope it does not have any typos.
Usage:

```
Huge_array my_array((size_t)10e9);
my_array[30000000]=10; // and so on upto size_t(10e9) - 1
```

If you need bigger values for value, you can make `vector<int>` to `vector<long>` or `vector<double>` or whatever in `Huge_array`.

Comment: i see, that's a good idea, but still apart from problem can't we do the same problem without accessing all the 10^9 elements i mean to say accessing only selected elements?

Comment: Well, wikipedia does not list any better solutions, and it would do if they had better Im quite sure. You can only do better if you have some speciality which you can take advantage of. That is why I asked what the original task was. Can you put up your weights? Are you interested in the precise or an approximate solution?

Comment: i guess i should've copied the question. Bdw i require precise solution.

Comment: Ok, then this should be it, there's no easy way out unfortunately in general.